# Coverting ReSRC.it htaccess to Nginx conf

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx

I'm attempting to covert the below code from Apache htaccess to Nginx conf to allow ReSrc.it to automatically rewrite the html images sources. The link to the documentation is available [here](http://www.resrc.it/docs/).  Here is the code that I am attempting to convert.

```
RewriteCond {%QUERY_STRING} ^.*resrc=0
RewriteRule /img/([^/]+) /img/$1 [L]
RewriteRule /img/([^/]+) http://app.resrc.it//www.your-domain.com/img/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advances for any assistance.